# LINQ var as field/column in where clause

Tags: c#, linq

In my entity, I have some fields/columns named like "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", etc. Each can have the values "s" or "n".

For example, if I try this:

```
items = items.Where(p => p.aaa == "s");
```

It will restrict the records to those with aaa having "s" (tested, it works).

I now need to pass a querystring with the name of the field to be searched.

```
var qsintervencao = Request.QueryString["intervencao"];

if (qsintervencao == "" || qsintervencao == null || qsintervencao == "all") {
    <a>TEST: </a> qsintervencao not set or set to all
} else {
    items = items.Where(p => p.@qsintervencao == "s");
    <a>TEST: </a> @qsintervencao
}
```

The QS works, qsintervencao (and TEST) outputs the selected field (aaa or bbb), however no records are returned.

Is there any way to pass a var into the where clause?

Comment: `qsintervencao == "" || qsintervencao == null || qsintervencao == "all"`  => `String.IsNullOrEmpty(qsintervencao) || qsintervencao == "all"`

Comment: What you're looking for reflection. It's questionable if it's really necessary. What's the motivation behind this?

Comment: It's just a statistics page for a research project. I can make an if clause for each one of the fields if there is no way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the related property dynamically by using *Reflection* like this;

```
  items = items.Where( p => p.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(property => property.Name == qsintervencao).GetValue(p, null) == "s");
```

Comment: error CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: How items has been declared ? Is it dynamic ?

Comment: var items = AsDynamic(App.Data["data"]);

Comment: It shouldn't be dynamic. Why don't you cast it as a class object ?

Comment: Not really a programmer... This is the way I call data from the CMS I'm using (DNN with 2sxc)

Comment: You can pull the data anywhere. It is not important. You should create class and its properties for data and cast it. Actually it is the only way to perform it.